# Is it possible to define my own exit codes in an Oracle Stored Procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In plsql scripts, you can do this with bind variables. Is it even possible to define your own exit codes in a procedure?

For example

```
WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH');
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file_handle);
   exit_code := 8675309;
```

I'm having trouble with a tool that calls this stored procedure, and even though the procedure is entering the above exception block (I intentionally gave a bad dir path), it is marking the stored procedure as successful after completion.

Comment: What are you doing with exit_code - is that a local variable, or an OUT parameter?

Comment: It is an OUT parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is with [`raise_application_error`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00705):

```
WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file_handle);
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH');
```

Execution of the current block will stop when the raise occurs, and it propogates up the call stack, first to any outer block, then whatever called that, and so until something cathes it. The caller receives the exception, and can see the code and the message. You are limited in the range of error codes you can produce though, and the example number you used isn't valid.

If you want those error numbers to be sigificant and consistent you can define them as constants in a package, potentially along with message text, but that's getting a bit off-topic...

In this specific case, since you're catching an existing exception, you can also just re-raise it:

```
WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH THEN
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file_handle);
   RAISE;
```

The caller will then see whatever error code is associated with that exception in the UTL_FILE package.

It's better to not rely on `dbms_output` for this sort of thing anyway, as your caller may not have handling for that available or enabled.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that I was using raise_application_error but that particular exception was an inner exception, and when control returned to the outermost exception, that wasn't being raised.